# Why does my for loop create an extra table-cell every iteration?

Tags: javascript, html-table, row

So i need to add a new cell to every row in my table with the index value of that row in it, i have a loop but it keeps adding on extra cell every time the loop runs.

i tried changing the loop and the insertcell() but it keeps adding the cell.

```js
//onderdeel 2, nieuwe table header voor rijnummers
var addTh = document.createElement("th");
var thText = document.createTextNode("Rij nummer");
addTh.appendChild(thText);
document.getElementById("uitvoertabel").rows[0].appendChild(addTh);

//Knop om een rij met gegevens toe te voegen
var button = document.getElementById("knop");
button.onclick = validate;


//Functie om te checken of gegevens kloppen
function validate() {
  var form = document.getElementById("invoerForm");

  if (form.vnaam.value == "") {
    alert("Voer uw voornaam in!");
    form.vnaam.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (form.anaam.value == "") {
    alert("Voor uw achternaam in!");
    form.anaam.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (isNaN(form.points.value) || form.points.value <= 0) {
    alert("Voer het aantal punten in!");
    form.points.focus();
    return false;
  }
  voegtoe();
  document.getElementById("voornaam").value = "";
  document.getElementById("achternaam").value = "";
  document.getElementById("punten").value = "";
}


//Functie om nieuwe rij gegevens aan de tabel toe te voegen
function voegtoe() {
  var formulier = document.getElementById("invoerForm");
  var nieuweGegevens = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < formulier.length; i++) {
    nieuweGegevens[i] = formulier.elements[i].value;
  }

  var uitvoertabel = document.getElementById("uitvoertabel");
  var nieuweRij = uitvoertabel.insertRow();
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var nieuweCell = nieuweRij.insertCell(i);
    nieuweCell.innerHTML = nieuweGegevens[i];
  }
  addIndex();
}


//Functie om rijnummers toe te voegen
function addIndex() {
  var table = document.getElementById("uitvoertabel");
  for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    var addIndex = table.rows[i].insertCell(-1);
    addIndex.innerHTML = table.rows[i].rowIndex;
    console.log(table.rows.length);
  }
}
```

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px dotted;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
  width: 60%;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<table id="uitvoertabel">
  <tr>
    <th>Voornaam</th>
    <th>Achternaam</th>
    <th>Aantal punten</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<br><br>

<form id="invoerForm" action="">
  <table id="invoertabel">
    <tr>
      <td>Voornaam:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="vnaam" id="voornaam"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Achternaam:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="anaam" id="achternaam"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Aantal punten:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="points" id="punten"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
</form>
<button id="knop">Voegtoe</button>
```

i expected the loop to just add one cell at the end of every row under "rijnummers", but every iteration it adds an extra cell on to each row that has come before it.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/X2n1T4R)

Comment: include sample html cod also.

Comment: It's because your `addIndex` function adds the index cell to each row in the table and you call it after you add a new row, so the rows that already have an index cell get a new one. The oldest row will have as many index cells as there are rows in the table - 1

Comment: Don't use a function that add the index cells. Add them directly after you create the row.

Comment: i got it working! thanks! :D